# One API Post request but Multiple Responses

Tags: reactjs, api, httpresponse

I have one Dropdown with 2 values let say dropdown value 1 and dropdown value 2 i have one post function that sends one image and selected dropdown value as input and returns response . in this case there is 2 dropdown and the response will differ based on selected dropdown value. how can i get and use different response with same POST request any help would be much appreciated(i am using reactjs to send request)

Comment: It's a bit unclear what your issue is, but if you do the _same_ POST request, you generally get the same response. But I guess you want to do a slightly different POST request? Try to explain your issue in more detail. Is this a frontend or backend problem. Include code.

Comment: bro  if i post data with Dropdown value 1 then i get response eg. name and id if i post with dropdown value 2 then i get response like image_url and id . i need to get specific data at a time and displays it

Comment: You responded to about half my comment. There's no way anyone can help you if you don't share your code.

Answer (score 0):

Giving you a conceptual idea for your solution. But Implementation is completely up to you. If you don't have access in rest api code then my suggestion is completely unusable.

1. Write a function in your API that accept your necessary parameters (Add extra Flag Parameter that will represent what type of Dropdown your selected).
2. Also if you want multiple return type in a api , you can use Tuple (in .net, ex: return new Tuple<int, int>(min, max).

Comment: bro i dont have access to api but the thing is if i post data with Dropdown value 1 then i get response eg. name and id if i post with dropdown value 2 then i get response like image_url and id .  i need to get specific data at a time and displays it

Comment: understood then its okay just place a if condition when u get your value. check for id and based on id you can bind or do anything with your value or image_url.

Comment: please see this question i explained it clearly https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69807045/api-calls-based-on-condition

Comment: @KarthikeyanM Please check the answer section : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69807045/api-calls-based-on-condition/69807141#69807141