# API Calls based on Condition

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, dropdown

I have a dropdown with two values (value 1 and value 2) and I have two API POST calls. I have one button, what I want is is the value one is selected perform the POST call for value 1 if value 2 is selected perform API post for value 2 and show their respective results. Please guide me how to achieve this.

MY POST Call:

```
submit(){
      const article = {  model: this.state.model,
        dataset:this.state.course,
        path:this.state.checkbox };

      axios.post('http://localhost:3000/home', article)
        .then(response => this.setState({ s3path: response.data.s3_path , triton_output: response.data.triton_output, confidence: response.data.confidence,
          inference_model:response.data.inference_model, loading: false,
        
        }))
        .catch(error => {
            this.setState({ errorMessage: error.message });
            console.error('There was an error!', error);
        });
        
       this.openModal();
       this.state.loading=true
    }
    submit1(){
      const article = {  model: this.state.model,
        dataset:this.state.course,
        path:this.state.checkbox };

      axios.post('http://localhost:3000/home', article)
        .then(response => this.setState({ x: response.data.x , y: response.data.y_output, height: response.data.height,
          inference_model:response.data.inference_model, loading: false,
        
        }))
        .catch(error => {
            this.setState({ errorMessage: error.message });
            console.error('There was an error!', error);
        });
        
       this.openModal();
       this.state.loading=true
    }
```

In this Post call the "Model:this.state.model" is the selected dropdown value. I need to call the API based on selected dropdown value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this code will solve your issue;

```
    var Test = React.createClass({
   onClick: function(event){
    if("Dropdown value check")
    {
        func1();
    }
    else{
        func2();
    }

   },
   render: function(){
      return (
         <a href="#" onClick={this.onClick}>Test Link</a>
      );
   }
});
```